# Running graphics in different resolutions

Tags: gdi+

I am creating a game using GDI+ and Raster images (2D images).  For performance sake, I believe that I should have the game changes the user's resolution to 800 x 600 and run the game in that setting.  However, the graphics look distorted in a wide screen since the aspect ratio for 800 x 600 is different than from a wide screen.  I cannot figure out how to determine the aspect ratio.

How is game programming normally handled on different resolutions?  Should I even change the user's resolution?  If I dont change the resolution, the game slows down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation I would advice to get device resolution that is most similar to your planned resolution or slightly bigger than it (800x600 -> 1024x720) and deal with it manually. Add black areas on sides or some artistic patterns that complement your game.

As already said GDI+ is not a common approach to 2D game nowadays, but the general principle of dealing with various screen aspects still stands.